# How to fix the bash syntax error

Tags: regex, bash

Here is my bash file,

The error message is:

```
command substitution: line 7: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
run-n2p4.sh: command substitution: line 8: syntax error: unexpected end of file
run-n2p4.sh: command substitution: line 8: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
run-n2p4.sh: command substitution: line 9: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

And here is the content:

```
#!/bin/bash

#this used to run 1 node and 1 core, 1 node and 8 cores and 2 nodes and 8 cores
for i in $(seq 1 1); do

    SEARCH_LARGE_ONE[3]=`qsub pbs41.sh -N "CCCdata-large_3” -q fast -l walltime=00:10:00 -l nodes=2:ppn=4 -v QUERY="CCCdata-large.txt"`

    SEARCH_LARGE_TWO[3]=`qsub pbs42.sh -N "CCCdata-large_3” -q fast -l walltime=00:10:00 -l nodes=2:ppn=4 -v QUERY="CCCdata-large.txt"`

done
```

could some one help me on that?

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the two `”`s to `"`.  Otherwise, there will be three `"` in each `qsub` command, which is an error.